# how to show that $\langle\sigma\rangle\cap\langle\tau\rangle$ is a trivial group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\sigma=(1 2)(3 4 5)$ and  $\tau=(1 2 3 4 5 6)$ in $S_6$, 
then show that 
$\langle\sigma\rangle\cap\langle\tau\rangle$ is a trivial group ?

My try :As i was googling it and find it and it is written that: Any power of $\sigma$ takes $1$ either to $1,$ or to $2.$ The only element of $\langle \tau \rangle$ which takes $1$ to $1$ is $\mathrm{id},$ and the only element which takes $1$ to $2$ is $\tau$ itself. But, on the other hand, any element of $\langle \sigma \rangle$ preserves $\{3,4,5\},$ which $\tau$ certainly doesn't. Thus
$$
\langle \sigma \rangle \cap \langle \tau \rangle =\{\mathrm{id}\}.
$$
I was reading this solution but ididn't understanding  anything..and  what does it mean to say ?

Pliz help me and tell me the proper solution in detail.....

Comment: The solution you googled is correct and written down properly. I'm not sure what you expect that we can add to that. Which parts don't you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rephrasing of the proof. If there are sentences or arguments you don't understand, say which ones in a comment, and I'll try to help you if I can.

Take a permutation $\gamma\in \langle \sigma\rangle\cap \langle \tau\rangle$. Because $\gamma\in \langle\sigma\rangle$, we have either $\gamma(1) = 1$ or $\gamma(1) = 2$.

- If $\gamma(1) = 1$, then because $\gamma\in \langle\tau\rangle$, we must have $\gamma = \text{id}$ (there is only one element in $\langle\tau\rangle$ that sends $1$ to $1$, and that's the identity)
- If $\gamma(1) = 2$, then because $\gamma\in \langle \sigma \rangle$, we have that the numbers $\gamma(3), \gamma(4)$ and $\gamma(5)$ are $3, 4$ and $5$ in some order. But this doesn't work with $\gamma \in \langle\tau\rangle$, because the only element in $\langle \tau\rangle$ that sends $1$ to $2$ is $\tau$ itself, which sends $5$ to $6$. Therefore $\gamma(1) = 2$ is impossible.

So the only possible option for $\gamma$ is $\text{id}$. This proves $\langle \sigma\rangle\cap \langle \tau\rangle = \{\text{id}\}$.

Comment: @ Arthur   im  not getting  ur 2 statement ,,that it is written that which send 5 to 1,,as from my view   6 is sending to 1,,

Comment: @Michael You're right, for some reason I thought $\tau = (12345)$ while writing that paragraph. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer@ Arthur but i have one doubt  $\langle \tau\rangle$ that send 1 to 2 and 6 to 1,,,my question is that   .....only element which  sends 1 to 2 is $\tau$ itself,,,that mean i can say that $\gamma(1) = 2$ ? but u say it is impossible,,,,,im not still getting

Comment: @Michael The second point is an argument by contradiction to reach the conclusion that $\gamma(1) = 2$ is impossible. We start by assuming that $\gamma(1) = 2$, and we arrive at the contradiction that $\gamma(5)$ must be either $3, 4$ or $5$ (since it's an element of $\langle \sigma \rangle$), but at the same time it must also be $6$ (because $\gamma$ must be equal to $\tau$).

Comment: @ Arthur ..thanks a lots  i got it,,,,,thank u

Answer (score 0):

Both permutations you wrote have order six, but their cycle structure as well as that of all their non-trivial powers are quite different:

Any power of a product of a two-cycle and a three-cycle (disjoint from the two-cycle) is either

- the identity permutation,
- a product of a two-cycle and a (disjoint) three-cycle,
- a single two-cycle, or
- a single three-cycle.

On the other hand, any power of a six-cycle is either

- the identity permutation,
- a six-cycle,
- a product of three disjoint two-cycles, or
- a product of two disjoint three-cycles.

So, the only element that can be both a power of $(1 2)(3 4 5)$ and of $(1 2 3 4 5 6)$ is indeed the identity.